# Should one put one's "Belbin team role" in the CV?

Tags: team, applications, resume, team-role

Is it appropriate to put one's ["Belbin team role"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Role_Inventories#Belbin_Team_roles) in a CV when applying for a standard job (as in, one that does not mention such a team role as a requirement)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to show it at the bottom (along with other interests, etc.) perhaps along with Briggs-Meyer type, it might be interesting and show your ability to do some self-reflection, but I wouldn't want to see it in the main body of the resume, if for no other reason than that most folks don't know what the heck it is!

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen a job posting that specified the "Belbin team role". I could see how when assembling a project team the team could need people from all these roles. These types would be pulled from current employees. I would be very surprised to see it mentioned in an advertisement.

I would be even more surprised to see it mentioned on a resume or CV.

Answer (score 3):

While I have never encountered a CV that stated the applicants Belbin team role (or other indicators like [MBTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator) ) I personally would see it as a significant positive.

I'd actually suggest that the appropriate place for this would be in a "professional development" section of the CV, as while you may have taken a self-test or worked through this for personal interest, many other people are exposed to this kind of profiling as part of professional development or leadership courses.

Knowledge of your own Belbin type also by extension implies some degree of knowledge of the other types, and that there are different strengths that people bring to a team environment.  It also suggests that you are aware of your (organisational) stengths and weaknesses, and will conduct yourself accordingly.

I would also see it as a sign of someone who was both "self aware", and comfortable with who they were.